# How do I transform a XML file into HTML using XSLT in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

how can i transform xml file( item.xml) into html using the xsl file ( item.xsl) and want to send it back to the client in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

See:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php

and

http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php